# How to open or click ListPreference automatically

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferences, listpreference

I have 2 activities - MainActivity and SecondActivity. MainActivity - activity with button, when I click on it, it refer me to the SecondActivity. SecondActivity - activity with preferences, including ListPreference. How to open or click on the ListPreference automatically while SecondActivity is opening?

Comment: have you created preferences in xml layout ?

Comment: @SohailZahid . yes, my preferences are in xml file

Comment: can you add you code ?

Comment: @SohailZahid xml code of preferences?

Comment: @SohailZahid ok. i have added java code

Comment: see this link http://alvinalexander.com/android/android-tutorial-preferencescreen-preferenceactivity-preferencefragment

Comment: @SohailZahid and what i need to see there? there no useful information here